# Store variable in session after login

Tags: php, laravel, session-variables

I'm new to Laravel framework and I need some help from you, guys!

What I'm trying right now is to add a new variable in session imediately after login.
This variable is dependent on the users that is logged in in that moment.
What I have right now is this, and it works but is not what I realy want:

```
$loggedUserId = Auth::id();
$getTenantId = DB::table('users')->select('tenant_id')->where('id', $loggedUserId)->get();
$tenantId = $getTenantId[0]->tenant_id;
Session::put('tenant_id', $tenantId);
```

The problem is that this code lives in home.blade.php and I don't want that because if, let's say, I want to make a system that when a user logs out and logs in again the page that appear after login is the last visited page before logout.

Where do I put this code so that it will be executed every time after a user logs in?

Comment: You **must** remove this code from your `home.blade.php`. Queries and session interaction should "live" outside your views.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But where should I put this code to be excuted imediately after login? I want to store that tenant_id in session but it's based on the user that is logged in. I have tried to put it in the loginController but there it says that Auth::id() is non existant.

Answer (score 1):

To execute an action right after an user is authenticated you may use Laravel's Events. Here's the doc that explain **exactly** how to subscribe to the event you are after: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events#event-subscribers

Comment: This looks interesting. I will look into it. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

[Create middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#defining-middleware) and put code there. Then add middleware to a `web` list (`app\Http\Kernel.php`) or [add middleware to a route group](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-group-middleware). Also, you could do the same your code does with just one line:

```
session()->put('tenant_id', auth()->user()->tenant_id);
```

And finally, in your case you don't even need to do all that stuff since `auth()->user()->tenant_id` and `Auth::user()->tenant_id` are globally available (in all controllers, views, models etc) for all logged in users.

Comment: Second thing works just fine for me. I have tried with the middleware too but I think I messed up something and it didn't work. THANK YOU!